# Sort comments by type in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component form with select filter:

```
 <template>
     <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="" v-model="filterRev" @change="filterReviews(filterRev)" class="form-control" id="">
                      <option value="0">All comments</option>
                      <option value="1">Good Comments</option>
                      <option value="2">Standard Comments</option>
                      <option value="3">Badd comment</option>
                    </select>
     </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 export default {
     data() {
        filterRev: 0
     },
     methods: {
        filterReviews(type) {
            if(Number.isInteger(parseInt(type))) {
                 this.$emit('filter', type);
            }
        },
     }
 }
 </script>
```

On component comments I have this:

```
        <div @filter="..." v-for="(comment, index) in items" :key="comment.id">
            <comment :data="comment"></comment>
        </div>
```

How I can check `comment.type` with `filter type`? I need sort comments, when user select certain filter. In `v-for` I have `comment.type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a data variable for the filter selection and a computed property to return the filtered comments:

1. Create a data variable in the container component to hold the selected filter type (e.g., `filterType`). Since the `filter` event from the selection component emits the filter ID in the event data (available in the template via [`$event`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)), we can use that to set `filterType` in the `@filter`-event handler:

   ```
   // template
   <filter-select @filter="filterType = $event" />

   // script
   data() {
     return {
       filterType: 0
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) in the container component to return the comment data that matches the filter selection. This uses [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the comment data array (i.e., `items` in this case).

   ```
   computed: {
     comments() {
       return Number(this.filterType) === 0
         ? this.items
         : this.items.filter(
             comment => Number(comment.type) === Number(this.filterType)
           );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Reference that computed property in your `v-for` loop:

   ```
   <comment v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" :data="comment" />
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw8jxzp0n7?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 0):

A great way to handle such kind of filters is by using [Vuex getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html). It's advance, but definitely will help you a lot in more complex scenarios.